# I'm trying to install apt-get onto an ARM64 using DPKG

Tags: debian, apt, synology

I have a Synology NAS - and I'm attempting to install `docker` onto it. 
To do that I need `apt-get` as my package manager, and nothing is panning out.

It seems like because I have ARM the methods I've been using only work for non-ARM systems.

Here's what I tried:

```
sudo wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.2.29ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
--2020-02-19 08:45:26--  http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.2.29ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
Resolving security.ubuntu.com... 2001:67c:1560:8001::11, 2001:67c:1360:8001::17, 2001:67c:1562::16, ...
Connecting to security.ubuntu.com|2001:67c:1560:8001::11|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1042028 (1018K) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: 'apt_1.2.29ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb'

apt_1.2.29ubuntu0.1 100%[===================>]   1018K  1.13MB/s    in 0.9s

2020-02-19 08:45:27 (1.13 MB/s) - 'apt_1.2.29ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb' saved [1042028/1042028]

sudo dpkg -i --force-bad-verify apt_1.2.29ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb --allow-unauthenticated
Authenticating apt_1.2.29ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
debsig: Origin Signature check failed. This deb might not be signed.

dpkg: verification on package apt_1.2.29ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb failed; but installing anyway as you requested
dpkg: error processing apt_1.2.29ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm)
dpkg: error processing --allow-unauthenticated (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt_1.2.29ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
 --allow-unauthenticated
```

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to install an amd64 package on a arm64 system, which will obviously fail. Seems Synology has its own package manager : https://github.com/SynoCommunity/spksrc/issues/3403 . As for Docker, see here : https://www.home-assistant.io/docs/installation/docker/ .